# Доступ к переменной JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Использую такую запись javascript:

```
var PM = {

    tabs: [],
    supportChat : $("#ChatWindow"),
    messagesWr : PM.supportChat.find("#ListDialog .list"),

    Init : function(){
        return socket = new io.connect('http://site.ru:8080');
    }

}
```

Как внутри этого класса обращаться к переменным этого же классе? , т-е нужно скажем в функции Init обратится к переменной `supportChat`, при такой записи пишет underfined и так тоже: `PM.supportChat`

Comment: > при такой записи

меняйте запись

Answer (score 4):

тыщу раз же уже говорено - **именованная ссылка на объект до его инициализации не существует.**

```
var PM = {

    tabs: [],
    supportChat : $("#ChatWindow"),

    Init : function(){
        return socket = new io.connect('http://site.ru:8080');
    }

}

PM.messagesWr=PM.supportChat.find("#ListDialog .list");
```

Comment: получается каждый раз обращаться к объектам через PM?

Comment: @IOleg а как вы хотели ? можно ещё сделать геттеры и сеттеры. или создать прототип, который использовать с помощью new;

Comment: @IOleg, ещё посмотрите на [вот этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/pQSCM/) - это по поводу вашей функции Init()

Answer (score 0):

```
Вроде у Стефана Стоянова что то такое видел:
```

var obj = {};

```
(function initObj () {
  obj.smtProp = smt;
  obj.smtProp2 = function () {
    // do something with obj.smtProp
  }
}());
```